# Is there a way to change the template typeahead.js uses based on an HTML attribute from where it's being called?

Tags: javascript, jquery, typeahead.js

I'm trying to tweak typeahead so that I can use one function call to dynamically display the data that corresponds to different form inputs.

Let's say I had the HTML below. I want to query the "foo" table and the "bar" table in my database:

```
    <div id="typeahead">
        <input name="foo" type="text"/>
    </div>

    <div id="typeahead">
        <input name="bar" type="text"/>
    </div>
```

Would there be a way to do something like:

```
$('input').typeahead(
{
    highlight: false,
    minLength: 1
},
{
    display: function(suggestion) { return null; },
    limit: 10,
    source: search,
    templates: {
        suggestion:
            /* if name is foo, show {{foo}}
             * if name is bar, show {{bar}}
             * etc.
             */
    }
});
```